# Month counts between dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have the below table. I need to count how many ids were active in a given month. So thinking I'll need to create a row for each id that was active during that month so that id can be counted each month. A row should be generated for a term_dt during that month.

```
 active_dt    term_dt      id
 1/1/2018                  101
 1/1/2018   5/15/2018      102
 3/1/2018   6/1/2018       103
 1/1/2018   4/25/18        104
```

Comment: What month is given?  Does an id have to be active for the entire month?

Comment: @GordonLinoff An id does not have to be active for the entire month.

Comment: What is the output you're expecting to see from the data you have supplied in your question? Please edit your question to add this information in.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is a "count number of overlapping intervals" problem. The algorithm goes like this:

- Create a sorted list of all start and end points
- Calculate a running sum over this list, add one when you encounter a start and subtract one when you encounter an end

  - If two points are same then perform subtractions first
- You will end up with list of all points where the sum changed

Here is a rough outline of the query. It is for SQL Server but could be ported to any RDBMS that supports window functions:

```
WITH cte1(date, val) AS (
    SELECT active_dt, 1 FROM @t AS t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COALESCE(term_dt, '2099-01-01'), -1 FROM @t AS t
    -- if end date is null then assume the row is valid indefinitely
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT date, SUM(val) OVER(ORDER BY date, val) AS rs
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT YEAR(date) AS YY, MONTH(date) AS MM, MAX(rs) AS MaxActiveThisYearMonth
FROM cte2
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=70754057a8b2e8325c1e3d071036f721)

Comment: Nice solution, could be improved by setting the 2nd type to `-1` (thus avoiding the `case`) and using `rows unbounded preceding` instead of the default `range` (which is usually  less efficient)

Comment: This does not seem to work if any of the active_dt values are prior to 2018.

Comment: @Chanicho: Of course it does work regardless of the year.

Answer (score 0):

I was toying with a simpler query, that seemed to do the trick, for Oracle:

```
with candidates (month_start) as (
    select to_date ('2018-' || column_value || '-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
    from 
      table 
       (sys.odcivarchar2list('01','02','03','04','05',
                             '06','07','08','09','10','11','12'))
),  sample_data (active_dt, term_dt, id) as (
  select to_date('01/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null,  101 from dual
  union select to_date('01/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
               to_date('05/15/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 102 from dual
  union select to_date('03/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
               to_date('06/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 103 from dual 
  union select to_date('01/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
               to_date('04/25/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 104 from dual
)
select c.month_start, count(1) 
from candidates c
join sample_data d 
  on c.month_start between d.active_dt and nvl(d.term_dt,current_date)
group by c.month_start
order by c.month_start
```

Comment: If you mean to pupulate sample_date, then no - I expect you would remove that part of my example, and replace sample_sata in the main select below with the actual data table you already have that has the data you want to count over...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use a hierarchical query, e.g.:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') active_dt, NULL term_dt, 101 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') active_dt, to_date('15/05/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') term_dt, 102 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('01/03/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') active_dt, to_date('01/06/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') term_dt, 103 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') active_dt, to_date('25/04/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') term_dt, 104 ID FROM dual)
SELECT active_month,
       COUNT(*) num_active_ids
FROM   (SELECT add_months(TRUNC(active_dt, 'mm'), -1 + LEVEL) active_month,
               ID
        FROM   your_table
        CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = ID
                   AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
                   AND LEVEL <= FLOOR(months_between(coalesce(term_dt, SYSDATE), active_dt)) + 1)
GROUP BY active_month
ORDER BY active_month;

ACTIVE_MONTH NUM_ACTIVE_IDS
------------ --------------
01/01/2018                3
01/02/2018                3
01/03/2018                4
01/04/2018                4
01/05/2018                3
01/06/2018                2
01/07/2018                1
01/08/2018                1
01/09/2018                1
01/10/2018                1
```

Whether this is more or less performant than the other answers is up to you to test.